# frequency in SAS without proc

Tags: sas, frequency

I want to make a frquency in my datastore but I don't know how to make it. I can't use procedure. I want to make something like that:

[image: structure]

But now I have only two first columns. I don't know how to divide by sum of all data from the second column. Thanks for help.

EDIT:
My code to get two first columns:

```
data dir.table1 (keep = gender summ);
set dir.table0;
by gender;
if first.gender then summ=0;
summ+1;
if last.gender then output;
run;
```

Comment: Could you post the code you used to get the first two columns? I think it's just a case of adding another aggregating AVG function after the COUNT (assuming 150,200 are counts).

Comment: Why can't you use a proc? Thats usually the fastest method.

Comment: Providing sample data and a minimal workable example is always a good idea!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted by Reeza, the standard way to do this is PROC FREQ.

As for other solutions:

**DATASTEP**

You cannot do that with one Datastep because you need to calculate the total of first. In my example bellow I use PROC SQL to calculate the total and store it in a macro variable and use it later on to calculate the percentage. You will also need to retain the variable sum, so that it will not be reset at every observation.

```
/* SELECT total number of rows and store it in a macro variable */
PROC SQL ;
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO :total FROM dir.table0;
QUIT;

DATA dir.table1 (KEEP=gender summ pct_tot);
    SET dir.table0;
    BY gender;

    /* Retain will keep the running total as you go through the dataset */
    RETAIN summ;

    IF first.gender THEN
        summ=0;

    summ+1;

    IF last.gender THEN DO;
        /* Calculate the percentage */
        pct_tot=summ / &total;
        OUTPUT;
    END;
RUN;
```

**PROC SQL**

IMHO SQL offers a much conciser way of getting the frequencies, by summing the number of total records within a non-coordinated subquery:

```
PROC SQL;
   CREATE TABLE dir.table1 AS 
   SELECT gender, 
          SUM(gender) AS summ, 
          SUM(gender) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dir.table0) AS pct_tot
     FROM dir.table0
    GROUP BY gender;
QUIT;
```